# Can I create a Running Totals Calculated Column in Ag Grid

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I want to create a new Custom Column in AG grid which will display the calculated value of another column together with the value of the column in the previous row.

We have created lots of calculated columns in AdapTable but i cannot work out how do this.

In our example we have a Price and a Date Column and a Running Price Calculated Column.

For the row where Date is Today, I want to the value in the Running Price column to be 'Price' in this Row plus whatever the Running Price value is in the Row where Date is Yesterday.

And for yesterday's row I want Running Price to include the value for 2 days ago. And so on.

Perhaps this example will help explain:

Price | Date | Running Price

5 | 2 Days Ago | 10

7 | Yesterday | 17

9 | Today | 26

If I can do this without needing to sort AG Grid on the Date column then even better as my users like to do their own sorts and I don't want it to break the running total.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done fairly easily in AdapTable.

You need to use what it calls an AggregatedScalarQuery.

Assuming that the columns in your grid are called 'Price', and 'MyDate' then the Expression for the 'RunningPrice' Calculated Column will be something like:

```
CUMUL(SUM([Price]), OVER([MyDate]))
```

See more at: https://docs.adaptabletools.com/guide/adaptable-ql-expression-aggregation-scalar#cumulative-aggregation

Edit: I should add that you dont need to sort the 'MyDate' column as per your initial message, since `OVER` will run over the dates in natural sort order.  So your users can continue to sort AG Grid how they like without it affecting your Calculated Column.